# How to change the band height dynamically?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to modify the height of detail band dynamically in jasper report? Because in my application i need to create pdf document.I have used one main document inside detail band of that main document i used one subreport. Sub report will take java bean as data source. This java bean return a list of field. So if we fixed the size of band then some time all values are not stretch in the document. Is it possible to change the detail band dynamically.

Answer (score 9):

```
JasperDesign jasper = JRXmlLoader.load(objeto.getRealPath("/reports/reportTaxType.jrxml"));
JRDesignBand banda = (JRDesignBand) jasper.getDetail();
banda.setHeight(2000); //YOU CAN SET THE SIZE THAT YOU WANT              
JasperReport report2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasper);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report2, parameters, ds);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `JRXmlLoader.load()` to create a `JasperDesign` object out of template file.  Use a method like `getPageHeader()` on the result to retrieve the band you want *and* cast the return value to `JRDesignBand`: returned object implements `JRBand`, but for `JasperDesign` it is always a `JRDesignBand`.  In the `JRDesignBand` class there is a `setHeight()` method.

Finally, use `JasperCompileManager.compileReport()` to create a `JasperReport` from the (now modified) `JasperDesign`.