# Set sizes of report bands in jasper report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

Let me know how to set the height of Detail band programmaticaly in iReport in swing application? That means, when the data filled in Detail band, then footer should be next, and no any white space.In my report when the few data filled in report, there is more white space till the page bottom.I want to remove that white space and set the column footer just after the last data in detail band.Thank you

Comment: Have you tried removing the areas you don't want, and using a conditional print in the target area?

Comment: I have removed the white space of detail band.Would let me know how to set conditional print with a sample code please?

Comment: When I arrive, I'm in the bus right now.

Answer (score 3):

You can set band via JasperReports API using [JRDesignBand class](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignBand.html#setHeight%28int%29):

```
public void JRDesignBand.setHeight(int height)
```

or via DynamicJasper API using [AbstractLayoutManager class](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/core/layout/AbstractLayoutManager.html#setBandFinalHeight%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignBand%29)

```
protected void AbstractLayoutManager.setBandFinalHeight(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignBand band)
```

- Sets the band's height to hold all its children

You can see samples:

1. with help of [JasperReports API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727083/how-to-change-the-band-height-dynamically)
2. and with help of [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref/ar/com/fdvs/dj/core/layout/AbstractLayoutManager.html)

You can also solve your problem without programming using only iReport. Try to set `ignore pagination` report property value to true:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ... isIgnorePagination="true"
```

You can also view this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233495/jasper-reports-how-to-get-column-footer-to-appear-directly-below-details-band).

JasperReports API allows to set this property using [JasperDesign class](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html#setIgnorePagination%28boolean%29) :

```
public void JasperDesign.setIgnorePagination(boolean ignorePagination)
```

- Sets the value of the ignore pagination flag

Answer (score 0):

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file);
JRDesignBand band = (JRDesignBand) jasperDesign.getPageFooter();
band.setHeight(SIZE);
```

You can change getPageFooter to another band...